# findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode error comes in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Everything works fine but when I submit data for the first time , this error comes. **findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference.**
What am I doing wrong?

```
import {Button, FormControl, FormHelperText, Grid, IconButton, InputAdornment, makeStyles, Paper, Snackbar, TextField, Typography} from '@material-ui/core';

import React from 'react';
import PersonIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Person';
import {Visibility, VisibilityOff} from '@material-ui/icons';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import VpnKeyIcon from '@material-ui/icons/VpnKey';
import {Link, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
import Alert from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';


const [isError,setError] = React.useState({
    nameError : false,
    passError : false,
    isErrorAlert : false
})
const [openAlert,setAlert] = React.useState(false);
//Destructuring
const {name , password} = RegisterUser;
//Functions

const HandleCloseAlert = () =>{
    setAlert(false)
}

const HandleOpenAlert = () => {
    setAlert(true)
}


const HandleRegister = () =>{
    if((name === '' || name === null) && (password === '' || password === null)){
        return setError({...isError ,nameError : true , passError : true})
    }
    else if((password === '' || password === null)){
        return setError({...isError,nameError : false , passError : true})
    }
    else if((name === '' || name === null)){
        return setError({...isError,nameError : true , passError : false})
    }
    // else if(!ValidUsername.test(name)){
    //     setError({nameError : true , passError : false , isErrorAlert : false})
    // }
        else{
            if(Users.length === 0){
                const UserObject = {}
                UserObject.name = name
                UserObject.password = password
                let newArray = [...Users , UserObject]
                setUsers(newArray)
                localStorage.setItem('users',JSON.stringify(newArray))
                // setError({...isError , isErrorAlert : false})
                HandleOpenAlert();
            }
            else{
                let UserName_array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')).map(user=>user.name)
                let found = UserName_array.includes(name)
                if(found){
                    setError({...isError , isErrorAlert : true})
                    // HandleOpenAlert();
                    alert('taken')
                }
                else{

                    const UserObject = {}
                    UserObject.name = name
                    UserObject.password = password
                    let newArray = [...Users , UserObject]
                    setUsers(newArray)
                    localStorage.setItem('users',JSON.stringify(newArray))
                    setError({...isError , isErrorAlert : false})
                    HandleOpenAlert();
                }
            }
    }
    

}
return ( 
    <div>
        <div className={classes.MainWrapper}>
            <>
            <Snackbar
            anchorOrigin={{
            horizontal : 'center',
            vertical : 'top'
            }}
            open = {openAlert}
            autoHideDuration = {1000}
            onClose = {HandleCloseAlert}
            >
            <Alert severity='success' variant='filled' onClose = {HandleCloseAlert}>'registed'</Alert>  
            </Snackbar>
            </>
        
            <Paper elevation = {3} className = {classes.Paper}>
                <Typography variant = 'h5' style={{margin : '10px'}}>Register</Typography>
                <div className={classes.FormWrapper}>
                    <form>
                        <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="flex-end">
                            <Grid item>
                                <PersonIcon/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                            <TextField
                            name = 'name'
                            type = 'text'
                            label="Username" 
                            size = 'medium'
                            error = {isError.nameError? true : false }
                            helperText={isError.nameError? 'Please Enter username correctly': ''}
                            value = {RegisterUser.name}
                            onChange = {HandleChange}
                            
                            />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <br />
                        <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="flex-end">
                            <Grid item>
                                <VpnKeyIcon/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                            <FormControl error = {isError.passError? true : false }>
                                <InputLabel htmlFor="standard-adornment-password">Password</InputLabel>
                                <Input
                                id="standard-adornment-password"
                                type={RegisterUser.showPassword? 'text' : 'password'}
                                name = 'password'
                                style={{width : '200px'}}
                                value = {RegisterUser.password}
                                onChange = {HandleChange}
                                endAdornment={
                                <InputAdornment position="end">
                                    <IconButton
                                    aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                                      onClick={HandleClickShowPassword}
                                    >
                                        {RegisterUser.showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                                    </IconButton>
                                </InputAdornment>
                                }
                                />
                                <FormHelperText id="component-helper-text">{isError.passError?'Please enter password':''}</FormHelperText>
                                </FormControl>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <br />
                        <Button variant='contained' color='secondary' onClick={HandleRegister} style={{marginTop : '10px', marginBottom : '10px'}}>Register</Button>
                        <br />
                        <Typography style = {{fontSize : '14px'}}>Already Logged in? <Link to = '/'>SignIn</Link></Typography>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </Paper>
        </div>
        
    </div> 
 );
```

}

export default Register;

Comment: What libraries/imports are you using? Probably there is a library or a module that has not been updated and is using legacy methods

Comment: updated. please check

Comment: In your react project run this command `npm update`. It will try to update all your project packages to the most recent version. In case this doesn't work. Do you know what component is causing this error?

Comment: in handleRegister when users.length === 0. whenever I try to call HandleOpenAlert() it gives error